# Unequal timepoints longitudinal data with missing values

Tags: time-series, panel-data, missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

I have a longitudinal data with unequal time points with missing values. I am looking for methods to impute the missing data. I looked at R packages NORM and AMELIA II and SAS procedures PROC MI. All of the implementations seems to work well with either cross- sectional data or longitudinal data with balanced time points. Will appreciate any ideas/ references for imputation of missing longitudinal data with unequal time points. Here is an example of what data looks like.

```
   ID   Date          v1    v2  v3
   1    3/7/1986    69.2    NA  30
   1    4/2/1987    70.3    30  30
   1    10/29/1988  71.8    30  35
   2    10/13/1993  71.2    NA  42
   2    10/24/1994  72.3    NA  53
   2    10/7/1996   74.2    31  57
   2    11/2/1998   76.3    32  52
   2    10/13/2000  78.2    29  41
   3    2/8/1999    89.1    29  20
   3    1/31/2000   90.2    30  22
   3    8/1/2000    90.5    29  24
   3    7/3/2001    91.4    25  NA
   3    10/15/2001  91.7    21  NA
   3    4/11/2002   92.2    15  NA
```

Comment: I do have similar issue when analyzing my data. Waiting for someone to help out.